# How to interact with another android app in tamper-proof way

Tags: android, kotlin

I am developing an app, which is soft dependent on what a user does in another app. E.g. my app may allocate a reward to to a user who shares our image on Instagram.

What can be the best way for my app to verify that the user has done this action. Let's say no API is available for me to verify existence of such a post on Instagram.

a) Does android allow one app to programmatically interact with another. To what extent this depends on what the other app allows, vs certain general features of the platform which are always true irrespective of other app's intention of preventing such interaction?

b) Secondly, if I go the brute force way (provided user permits), can I simulate user actions and launch the other app and interact with it on behalf of the user, much like using the Win32 API and simulating a mouse click or keyboard input?

c) Basically, I just want a screen shot of the user showing me the post has been shared. My simplest goal is to verify that the screenshot is indeed from the other app, and not a static image or a fake app looking like the original?

Any guidance or general advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks
Asif

Comment: "Does android allow one app to programmatically interact with another" -- not generally. "can I simulate user actions and launch the other app and interact with it on behalf of the user" -- not generally. Accessibility services can do those sorts of things. However, those have serious security ramifications, leading to lots of nasty on-device warnings, restrictions on distribution on places like the Play Store, and possibly regulation in certain jurisdictions. Have you discussed your plans with an attorney?

Comment: @CommonsWare +1 just 2 things to add `b)` can possibly be done, but on a rooted device. And regarding `c)`, what is stopping the user to share it, then delete it 2 seconds after your verification? Basically what you want (to know for sure that the user shared and has the shared post) is more or less impossible due to pure logistics, not even going into technical stuff.

Comment: @CommonsWare I'm not sure, what do you mean by "not generally' answer to a). Yes, Android always allows for direct communication between apps, of course if they both want to talk to each other. Answering a subquestion: "To what extent this depends on what the other app allows" - fully. You can only do as much as the 3rd party intentionally allows you. You can't force it to do anything (without root or exploiting some bugs).

Comment: @Broot: Sorry, I had already leapt ahead to the other portions of the question and let the OP's intentions (manipulate another app) color my answer to a).